# How to plot the following graph

Tags: pgfplots, diagrams, graphs

I am new in LaTeX and learning the plotting, I am trying to plot `$y=x^2$` where `xmin=0` and `ymin=0` but I don't want numeric points on the axis instead I need (k,0) and (0,k) and a line joining these two and making rectangle also intersecting with the graph `$y=x^2$`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Never use `x^2` instead of `x*x` when computing. Even when it works, you are adding an unneccesary complication. Worst case you compute `exp{2*log(x)).`/

Comment: Hmmm, your rectangle intersect the parabola only if k=1. Or did you mean (0,k²) and (k, 0)? –

Answer (score 2):

I really like [pgfplots](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots).

How about this as a start:

*Edit:* small improvements without making it too complicated

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    small,
    axis lines=center,
    xmin=0,ymin=0,
    domain=0:1.5,
    xtick=\empty,
    ytick=\empty,
    no markers,
    extra x ticks={1},
    extra x tick labels={${(k,0)}$},
    extra y ticks={1},
    extra y tick labels={${(0,k)}$},
    ]
\addplot {x^2};
\addplot coordinates {(1,0)(1,1)(0,1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this one:

[image]

with this code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[gray!15,step=.5] (-.5,-.5) grid (3.5,9.5);
    \draw[thin,->] (-.5,0)--(3.5,0) node[above] () {$x$};
    \draw[thin,->] (0,-.5)--(0,9.5) node[above] () {$y$};
    \draw[domain=0:3, smooth, variable=\x, line width=2pt, blue] plot ({\x}, {\x*\x});
    \draw[red,thin] (2.8,0) rectangle (0,2.8);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, but I need both lines should intersect at the point of the curve

Comment: I don't understand. Perhaps you need to change this line \draw[red,thin] (2.8,0) rectangle (0,2.8); in \draw[red,thin] (1,0) rectangle (0,1);

Answer (score 0):

R plots are not designed to mimic pfgplots style, so draw axis with arrows and custom ticks labels ruins the simplicity of code, but just for the record, an `example.Rnw` using `knitr`:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\begin{document}
<<dev='tikz',echo=F,fig.width=3.5,fig.height=3.5>>=
x=seq(0,10,.1)
y=x^2
xlim <- c(min(x),max(x));
ylim <- c(min(y),max(y));
plot(x,y,type = "l", lty = 1, axes = F, frame = F,col="blue",xlab="",ylab="",xlim=xlim,ylim=ylim) 
axis(1, mgp=c(0,-.5,0), las=1, tick=F, at =5,label="(k,0)")
axis(2, mgp=c(0,-.5,0), las=2, tick=F, at =5^2,label="(0,k)")
mtext('y',3,1,at=0,las=1); ## y label
mtext('x',4,1,at=0,las=1); ## x label
segments(x0 =5, y0 =0, x1 =5, y1 =5^2, col = "red") 
segments(x0 =0, y0 =5^2, x1 =5, y1 =5^2, col = "red") 
arrows(c(0,xlim[1]),c(ylim[1],0),c(0,xlim[2]),c(ylim[2],0),0.05)
@
\end{document}
```